# MVC - variable defined in cshtml not available in bundled javascript file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

None of my inline script variables defined below are accessible from the `depositreview` javascript file that you see in the `@Scripts.Render` line below.

```
@section Scripts {   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/trader/mobile/depositreview")
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addFundAccountRequest: "@Url.Action("AddFundAccountRequest", "FundTransfer")";
    var depositReviewUrl = '@Url.Action("DepositReviewMobile", "FundTransfer")';
    var paymentProviderUrl = '@Url.Action("PaymentProviderMobile", "FundTransfer")';
    var account = '@Model.Account';
   ...etc...
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the first variable I define below has a `:` instead of an `=` sign.  This caused all the variables to not be defined and there was no runtime error to let me know.  Took hours for me to figure this out.

```
@section Scripts {   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/trader/mobile/depositreview")
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addFundAccountRequest: "@Url.Action("AddFundAccountRequest", "FundTransfer")";
    var depositReviewUrl = '@Url.Action("DepositReviewMobile", "FundTransfer")';
    var paymentProviderUrl = '@Url.Action("PaymentProviderMobile", "FundTransfer")';
    var account = '@Model.Account';
  ...etc...
</script>
}
```